# Database query not working with xeditable plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a table with popup unabled editing with xeditable plugin and trying submit my data with ajax call to the database. The following is my table row code:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"#\" id='sel' data-pk=\"$row[loan_id]\">" . $row['loan_status'] . "</a></td>";
```

I have tried debugging and in the Network tab of firefox I could see the data being posted as follows :
Form Data:
name : "loan_amount"
value: "2000"
pk: "1"

but the response from the post.php is this field is required . Here is my post.php code

```
$pk = $_POST['pk'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    /*
     Check submitted value
    */
    if(!empty($value)) {

$result = mysql_query('update k_loans set '.mysql_escape_string($name).'="'.mysql_escape_string($value).'" where loan_id ="'.mysql_escape_string($pk).'"');

       print_r($_POST);
    } else {

        echo "This field is required!";
    }
```

My jquery code for th xeditable plugin is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     

$('#loan a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'loan_amount',
    url: '../payments/post.php',
    title: 'Enter amount',
    ajaxOptions: {
     type: 'put'

   }   

});

});
```

But i am unable to understand the issue as the query seems perfectly fine to me , still the database is not getting updated .

Anyone who can guide me in the right direction  . Thanks

Comment: I suggest you try three things in the PHP: (1) print the $_POST array before you query the database - if there's a DB error you won't see it (2) format your query into a PHP string varaiable and print it - I think that's your problem, (3) always pay attention to mysql errors

Comment: @bitfiddler Thanks for stopping by and suggesting , but I have resolved it and posted the solution as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with the script provided by the xeditable on their github uses mysql which is not safe to use these days . So I have shifted all of them to use mysqli. Here is the working code for anyones reference :

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";

$con = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error($con));
echo "Cudnt cnnect";}
else{
echo "connected";
} 

    var_dump($_POST); 

    $pk = $_POST['pk'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    /*
     Check submitted value
    */
    if(!empty($value)) {

if ($result =  mysqli_query($con,'update k_loans set '.mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name).'="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$value).'" where loan_id ="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$pk).'"'));
{
        echo "Update successful";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
       print_r($_POST);
    } else {

        echo "This field is required!";
    }
?>
```